# Configuring sendmail to use one outbound MTA exclusively

Tags: sendmail

I have a sendmail problem, and I'm anything but a sendmail guru -- I could use some help.

My problem is that I have a system intended to be more or less an "appliance" -- it's not intended to have an admin. Because of this, it needs to be able to "call home" by sending email.  As we have configured it, this works fine -- using sendmail, it finds the appropriate relay by looking up an MX record and everything works fine.

Now, however, because of security concerns, we want to limit it to using *exactly one* relay, so for example `relay.corp.example.com`.  Should the user configure it to use, say, `fubar.example.com`, the mail sending should fail or be deferred.

I thought that by configuring sendmail with a `/etc/mail/server.switch` file containing

```
hosts   files
```

without `dns`, I'd get that effect.  This doesn't work -- instead, if it gets mail addressed to `foo@example.com`, it tries to talk directly to `example.com`, and ignores the configured server.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Okay, I tied both schemes experimentally, and they both seem to work.  Wish I could mark them both correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using m4 to build your `sendmail.cf`? If so, you should add

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay.corp.example.com')
```

to your `sendmail.mc` and regenerate your `sendmail.cf`.
It looks like adding

```
DSrelay.corp.example.com
```

right to the `sendmail.cf` will do the trick too.

Comment: He shoots, he scores.  Thanks.  Now to make the %^#$@#^$% application rewrite its sendmail.cf....

Answer (score 1):

Here is an M4 file for a SuSE system for simply forwarding ALL email to the relay host.
(Its included in the SuSE distribution as well).  You simply do m4 x.mc >x.cf where x.mc is the file below and x.cf would be the file to replace your sendmail.cf file (usually in either /etc/sendmail.cf or /etc/mail/sendmail.cf).

```
 divert(-1)
 #
 # Copyright (c) 1999 SuSE GmbH Nuernberg, Germany.
 # Copyright (c) 2006 SuSE LINUX Products GmbH, Germany.
 # Author: Werner Fink
 # Please send feedback to http://www.suse.de/feedback/
 #
 # This is a special case -- it creates a stripped down configuration
 # file containing nothing but support for forwarding all mail to a
 # central hub via a local SMTP-based network.  The argument is the
 # name of that hub.
 #

 include(`/usr/share/sendmail/m4/cf.m4')
 divert(0)dnl
 VERSIONID(`@(#)Setup for SuSE Linux     0.2 (SuSE Linux) 2002/01/14')
 dnl
 dnl  This is the default configuration for SuSE Linux.
 dnl  See /usr/share/sendmail/ostype/suse-linux.m4
 dnl  and /usr/share/sendmail/README for more information.
 dnl
 OSTYPE(`suse-linux')dnl
 dnl
 dnl  A stripped down configuration. Replace the mailhub.domain.notused
 dnl  with your real mailhub.
 dnl
 FEATURE(`nocanonify')dnl
 FEATURE(`nullclient', `relay.corp.example.com')dnl
 dnl
 dnl  This line is required for formating the /etc/sendmail.cf
 dnl
 LOCAL_CONFIG
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd just now read about the nullclient feature and was wondering how to configure it.